# Convert mySQL queries to Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I'm new to laravel new and needed solution for database query. 
I have below raw query:

```
SELECT SUM(un.uni_duration) AS course_duration FROM xxcourse_components xx
INNER JOIN courses co ON co.cou_id = xx.cco_version
INNER JOIN modules mo ON mo.mod_id = xx.cco_component
INNER JOIN xxmodule_units xu ON xu.modu_module = mo.mod_id
INNER JOIN units un ON un.uni_id = xu.modu_unit
WHERE co.cou_id = "6"
AND un.deleted_at IS NULL;
```

I try to convert to laravel as query builder:

```
return DB::table('xxcourse_components as xx')
            ->select('SUM(un.uni_duration) as course_duration')
            ->join('courses as co', 'co.cou_id', '=', 'xx.cco_version')
            ->join('modules as mo', 'mo.mod_id', '=', 'xx.cco_component')
            ->join('xxmodule_units as xu', 'xu.modu_module', '=', 'mo.mod_id')
            ->join('units as un', 'un.uni_id', '=', 'xu.modu_unit')
            ->where('co.cou_id ', '=', $cou_id)
            ->whereNull('un.deleted_at')
            ->get();
```

However the result get me the error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'SUM(un.uni_duration)' in 'field list' (SQL: select `SUM(un`.`uni_duration)` as `course_duration` from `xxcourse_components` as `xx` inner join `courses` as `co` on `co`.`cou_id` = `xx`.`cco_version` inner join `modules` as `mo` on `mo`.`mod_id` = `xx`.`cco_component` inner join `xxmodule_units` as `xu` on `xu`.`modu_module` = `mo`.`mod_id` inner join `units` as `un` on `un`.`uni_id` = `xu`.`modu_unit` where `co`.`cou_id` = 6 and `un`.`deleted_at` is null)

any clues to solve the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `selectRaw`:

```
return DB::table('xxcourse_components as xx')
    ->selectRaw('SUM(un.uni_duration) AS course_duration')
    ->join('courses as co', 'co.cou_id', '=', 'xx.cco_version')
    ->join('modules as mo', 'mo.mod_id', '=', 'xx.cco_component')
    ->join('xxmodule_units as xu', 'xu.modu_module', '=', 'mo.mod_id')
    ->join('units as un', 'un.uni_id', '=', 'xu.modu_unit')
    ->whereRaw('co.cou_id = ?', [$cou_id])
    ->whereNull('un.deleted_at')
    ->get();
```

Note: I also refactored your `WHERE` clause to use `whereRaw` with a statement parameter.  Ideally you should be using a prepared statement to avoid SQL injection.  Though, if you can verify that `$cou_id` only contains numbers, then the injection risk should be minimal.

Comment: I believe the normal 'where()' in laravel will also generate a prepared statement. No need to manually pull that apart.

Comment: @RobBiermann Can you provide a reference or example of that?  (I don't know the answer myself).

Comment: `Date::where('date', '2019-01-01')->get()` results in `select * from dates where date = ?` with a binding for  `"2019-01-01"`. Note that Date is a model in this case

Comment: You can see the executed statement if you run `DB::enableQueryLog()` beforehand and `dump(DB::getQueryLog());` after your query

Comment: @Time Biegeleisen, thanks mate, but can I know why select() will cause an error instead of selectRaw() ?

Comment: @BenKoo The regular `select()` function in Laravel only allows selecting ordinary columns.  To select anything else, you need `selectRaw()`, see the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#selects).

Answer (score 0):

Use \DB::raw on your select, like this:

```
...
->select(\DB::raw('SUM(un.uni_duration) as course_duration'))
...
```

You can find the documentation here [Laravel Raw Expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#raw-expressions)

Comment: `selectRaw()` is a shorter/cleaner alternative